# Use RedirectToAction in a JsonResult Action?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-controller

using ASP.NET MVC 1.0 and I have a action that returns a JsonResult and I need to redirect another action that also returns a JsonResult action type.

The problem is the RedirectToAction() returns a RedirectToRouteResult class and seems there is no way to convert that to JsonResult class ?

This is the error I am getting;
Error 124 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Web.Mvc.RedirectToRouteResult' to 'System.Web.Mvc.JsonResult'

Comment: Just change return type to `ActionResult`.

Comment: This [answer][1] is 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2864972/how-to-redirect-to-a-controller-action-from-a-jsonresult-method-in-asp-net-mvc
probably more helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So you have Action method A, which in some situation, needs to return the result from Action Method B?

Why not just do something like this:

```
public JsonResult ActionMethodA()
{
     if(someCondition)
        return ActionMethodB();
     else
        return new JsonResult();
}

public JsonResult ActionMethodB()
{
    // Something
}
```