# How to retrieve data via jQuery AJX/JSON call and display error if validation fails

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

How do I retrieve data via an AJAX/JSON call and display an error message on the page if the validation or call failed for what ever reason?

I am using ASP.NET MVC 5 together with jQuery.

I have an add form with multiple textboxes, what this page adds is irrelevant.  One of the textboxes is for an employee number to be filled in, for example 123456.  Right next to this textbox I have a button labeled "Populate Employee Details".  What this button does is if it is clicked it does a service call to retrieve all this employee's details from an external data source.  It then fills in certain textboxes with the data that it returned from the service call.  This button is not the submit button to submit the form data to be saved in the database.  It's just an additional button on the form to do an external lookup.  This is what it looks like:

[image]

The partial HTML code for the above section is as follows:

```
<tr>
     <td class="edit-label">Employee Number: <span class="required">**</span></td>
     <td>
          @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.EmployeeNumber, new { maxlength = "6" })
          @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.EmployeeNumber)
          <button id="PopulateEmployeeDetailsButton" type="button">Populate Employee Details</button>
     </td>
</tr>
```

The jQuery code for the above section is as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $('#PopulateEmployeeDetailsButton').click(function () {
          var url = '/Application/GetEmployeeDetails';
          var data = { employeeNumber: $('#EmployeeNumber').val() };

          $.getJSON(url, data, function (data) {
               $('#Title').val(data.Title);
               $('#FirstName').val(data.FirstName);
               $('#LastName').val(data.LastName);
          });
     });
});
```

The GetEmployeeDetails action method that returns a JSON result set:

```
public ActionResult GetEmployeeDetails(string employeeNumber)
{
     Employee employee = employeeService.GetEmployeeDetails(employeeNumber);

     return Json(employee, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

My view model for this form looks something like this:

```
public class ApplicationViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
     [Required(ErrorMessage = "Employee number is required")]
     [StringLength(6, MinimumLength = 6, ErrorMessage = "Employee number must consist of 6 numbers")]
     [RegularExpression(@"^\d+$", ErrorMessage = "Employee number must be numeric")]
     public string EmployeeNumber { get; set; }

     [Required(ErrorMessage = "First name is required")]
     public string FirstName { get; set; }

     [Required(ErrorMessage = "Last name is required")]
     public string LastName { get; set; }

     // I have left out the rest
}
```

The above works fine if I click on the form's submit button, then all these error messages display depending what type of error it is.

What I need to implement is the following.  When the user clicks the "Populate Employee Details" button, I also need validation to be performed, preferably before I do the service call.  And if something doesn't validate properly I need the validation to fire and display the error messages like it would have when I clicked on the form's submit button.  And if the service call failed (maybe because it is not working) then I need it to go to my generic error page the same way that it would of when an error occurs in my ASP.NET MVC application.

How would I do this?

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood correctly you want to manually validate the form before firing the ajax call.

The validation plugin has a `valid()` method that can be called on the form that will trigger the validation and also everything that is associated with it (error messages, input becoming red, etc. etc.). The docs are here: http://jqueryvalidation.org/valid/

The docs specify that the `.validate([options])` method must have been called already on the form, but if you are using the MVC unobtrusive validation as you probably are, this has already been done for you.

In short, you can do:

```
 $('#PopulateEmployeeDetailsButton').click(function (ev) {
      if ($('form').valid()) {
          // web service call ...
      } else {
          ev.preventDefault();
          return false;
      }
 });
```

For the redirect to error if the service call fails, you have to do it in your callback: refer to this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2864972/how-to-redirect-to-a-controller-action-from-a-jsonresult-method-in-asp-net-mvc) for details.

With `.getJSON()` you have the option of chaining callbacks like this (simplified from the docs):

```
$.getJSON(url, data, function (data) {
    $('#Title').val(data.Title);
    $('#FirstName').val(data.FirstName);
    $('#LastName').val(data.LastName);
})
.fail(function() { 
    // redirect to error here...
});
```

Comment: Yes I would like validation to be done on client before the call is made, and also after the call is made. What happens if the employee number does not exist? I need an error message for this to be displayed as well.

Comment: After the webservice call you can simply do `$('form')valid()` again to revalidate... For the error it's up to you, you can return a `404` and handle it in the fail or return a specific Json result and handle it in the callback... You should have all the elements to operate on your code now :)